# Jquery click doesn't switch class in Internet Explorer or Firefox

Tags: jquery

This function works fine in chrome, but doesn't work in explorer or firefox.

```
 $('a#navclick').click(function(){
 var iclick = $(this).attr('data-iclick');
 var clickimg = $(this).attr('click-data-bgsrc'); 
 if ($('#topId').hasClass('topOn'))
 {
   $('#bg img[src="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
   $('#bg img[src!="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 }
 else
 {
 $('#bg img[src="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("inactive", "active", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 $('#bg img[src!="'+clickimg+'"]').switchClass("active", "inactive", 0, "easeInOutQuad");
 $('#topId').show("slide", {direction:"up"}, 1000);
 $('#topId').addClass('topOn');
 $('#mainId').hide("drop", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
 }
```

Everything works on it but the switch of the image class.  That won't work unless I comment out the line;

```
    $('#mainId').hide("drop", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
```

Once I do that it works in everything.  What could stop it from completing just because it is hiding that div too?

Here is the HTML

```
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/hashchange.js"></script>
            <script src="js/hoverbuild.js"></script>
            <script src="js/iclick.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="sitewrapper">
            <div id="bgover" class="over">
            <div class="contactUp rounded-corners" id="keep">
            <form>
            <h1>Contact </h1>
            <label>
            <span>Your Name</span><input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
            </label>
            <label>
            <span>Your Email Address</span><input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
            </label>
            <label>
            <span>Subject</span><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
            </label>
            <label>
            <span>Message</span><textarea id="feedback" name="message"></textarea>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit Form" />
            </label>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bg">
              <img src="images/bg.jpg" class="active">
              <img src="images/bg2.jpg" class="inactive">
              <img src="images/hsna.jpg" class="inactive">
              <img src="images/happening.jpg" class="inactive">
              <img src="images/rok.jpg" class="inactive">
              <img src="images/life.jpg" class="inactive">
              <img src="images/history.jpg" class="inactive">
            </div>
            <div class="mainpage">
            <div class="social">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="calendar"><img src="images/calendar.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="donate"><img src="images/donate.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="info"><img src="images/info.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="cMail"><img src="images/mail.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mainnav" id="mainId">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
            <ul class="nav">
            <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/hsna.jpg"><a href="#">HSNA</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/hsnaMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            <li class="hoverbg" id ="life" data-bgsrc="images/life.jpg"><a href="life">LIFE</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/lifeMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/happening.jpg"><a href="happening">HAPPENING</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/happeningMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/porchrokr.jpg"><a href="porchrokr">ROK</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/porchrokrMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            <ul>
            <li><img src="images/ring.png"></li>
            <li><a href="instagram"><img src="images/instagram.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="pinterest"><img src="images/pinterest.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="youtube"><img src="images/youtube.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="topId">
            <a href=#><img src="images/hsna-logo-small.png"></a>
            <ul class="subTopMenu">
            <li class="noHover" data-navht="200px"><a href="#">HSNA</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/hsnaMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            <li class="noHover" data-navht="200px"><a href="life">LIFE</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/lifeMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            <li class="noHover" data-navht="200px"><a href="happening">HAPPENING</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/happeningMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            <li class="noHover" data-navht="225px"><a href="porchrokr">ROK</a>
            <?php
            include("includes/rokMenu.php");
            ?>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            <ul>
            <li><img src="images/ring.png"></li>
            <li><a href="http://instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/pinterest.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/ target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
            </ul
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes it is in the head of the page as;  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: Are there any errors in the firefox javascript console?

Comment: No no errors showing up